# How does orphans/widows works?

Tags: css, pdf-generation

Trying to print some web content with adequate layout (no 1-2 lines orphans/widows), I am unable to get any expected result.

Let consider the following example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <style>
    body
    {
        font-size: 2em;
        width: 190mm;
    }
    p:before
    {
        content: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Praesent eleifend dapibus felis, a consectetur nisl aliquam at. Aliquam quam augue, molestie a scelerisque nec, accumsan non metus. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Proin cursus euismod nisi, a egestas sem rhoncus eget. Mauris non tortor arcu. Pellentesque in odio at leo volutpat consequat.... ";
    }
    
    section
    {
        widows: 10;
        orphans: 10;
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<article class="section">
<p/><p/><p/>
</article>

<article class="section">
<p/><p/><p/>
</article>

<article class="section">
<p/><p/><p/>
</article>
</body>
</html>
```

When I open this file in (e.g.)Chromium, then I print the content to PDF and open that file.

We can see paragraphs starting 3-4 lines before the end of the page, and others finishing 3-4 lines after the beginning of the page.

[image]

I suppose that `orphans` and `widows` only work for the immediate content of the element with that style. However real life requirements is exactly the reverse: we want high-level elements to not start close to new pages, and leaf elements are usually not that important.

I am probably misunderstanding how to those styles works.

Comment: Are you sure widows, orphans work in before content? I would try with regular flow content first.

Comment: It does yes, but I don't need it, so feel free to write a big text instead.